# Link inside webpage always return "404 not found" error if opened from webview ~Android ~Java

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview that opens up a webpage that contains a some links. However, if I click on each link, it will show "404 Not Found" error. I have done the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` inside WebViewClient, but it results the same.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

this is how I set my `webview`:

```
WebView web_view = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
WebSettings webSettings = web_view.getSettings();
web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
         progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
         super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
     }
 });
 web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     }
     @Override
    public void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview view, String url){
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view,url);
    }
 })
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 web_view.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
```

I have also done this:

```
    @Override
    public void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview view, String url){
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

but both of them result in '404 not found'.

Any help please..

Comment: Make you have internet connection, have proper permission in manifest file and url is working one

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the layout to show when an error occurred instead of Web Page (a dirty 'page not found message') The layout has one button, "RELOAD" with some guide messages.

If an error occurred, Remember using boolean and show the layout we prepare.

If user click "RELOAD" button, set mbErrorOccured to false. And Set mbReloadPressed to true.
if mbErrorOccured is false and mbReloadPressed is true, it means webview loaded page successfully. 'Cause if error occurred again, mbErrorOccured will be set true on onReceivedError(...)
Here is my full source. Check this out.

public class MyWebViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

```
private final String TAG = MyWebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private WebView mWebView = null;
private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
private LinearLayout mlLayoutRequestError = null;
private Handler mhErrorLayoutHide = null;

private boolean mbErrorOccured = false;
private boolean mbReloadPressed = false;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRetry)).setOnClickListener(this);
    mlLayoutRequestError = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLayoutRequestError);
    mhErrorLayoutHide = getErrorLayoutHideHandler();

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewMain);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(getChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.btnRetry) {
        if (!mbErrorOccured) {
            return;
        }

        mbReloadPressed = true;
        mWebView.reload();
        mbErrorOccured = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }
    else {
        finish();
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (mbErrorOccured == false && mbReloadPressed) {
            hideErrorLayout();
            mbReloadPressed = false;
        }

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        mbErrorOccured = true;
        showErrorLayout();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
}

private WebChromeClient getChromeClient() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyWebViewActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    return new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    };
}

private void showErrorLayout() {
    mlLayoutRequestError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideErrorLayout() {
    mhErrorLayoutHide.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(10000, 200);
}

private Handler getErrorLayoutHideHandler() {
    return new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mlLayoutRequestError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this... this is the code from AS default webview activity, generated by AS.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google);
    initInstances();

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}
```

sidenote :-->>  iinitInstances() is referring to nagivation drawer on the left, could be ignored.